# Python PANDAS: Compute differences between multiple sets of two columns, mapping difference to another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the start time and end time for 21 different sections of a survey in my data set.  I want to computer the difference between the end time and the start time for each of the surveys, and put that data in a survey specific column.

Start time and End time is in HH:MM:SS

Here was my implementation:

```
def getSec(s):
    l = s.split(':')
    return int(l[0]) * 3600 + int(l[1]) * 60 + int(l[2])
```

...After importing csv into dataFrame, I do

```
 timeDifferences = {}
 sections =['1','2','3','4','5','6','7_1','7_2','7_3','8_1','8_2','8_3','9_1','9_2','9_3','11_1','11_2','12','15','16','17','18_1','18_2','19','21']    
 for i in sections:
   timeDifferences["s"+i+"_time"] = (getSec(df["s"+i+"_etimestamp"]) - getSec(df["s"+i+"_stimestamp"]))* 60
```

The problem is that I'm doing getSec on an entire series, rather than an individual dataset.  I'm new to Pandas, so I can't conceptualize how to work on the entire array simultaneously.

How would I go about doing this without three nested for loops?

Comment: It would be much easier (to reason about and vectorize) if you had the date too and could create a Timestamps :)

Comment: dates are contained in "s"+i+"_startdate"

Comment: It may possible perhaps you can read them in directly as Timestamps using pd.read_csv's parse_dates argument.

Comment: perhaps it would help to see the first few lines of the csv?

Comment: I can't do your first suggestion because there are 21 columns, each with its own HHMMSS time stamp (the time at which they started the section).  The data set is proprietary, so I can't show it.  Apologies.  Do you understand the issue, though?  What can I explain better?

Comment: @Parseltongue even without showing us you can still call `read_csv` and use param `parse_dates=my_col_list`, the list can be either the column names or the index value, this would be easier than parsing after loading. Also you can get the seconds of these values by accessing the attribute `.second` rather than what `getSec` is doing, in fact you seem to be calculating time difference in minutes so why not just subtract the values and then access the `.minute` attribute. Another idea would be to use [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Comment: so my_col_list should be a reference to 21 independent start dates and start times?  the data is separated like s1_startdate s1_starttime s1_enddate s1_endtime, for 21 different sections.  I'm confused as to what my_col_list has to be

Comment: @Parseltongue you can aggregate the different components of the date cols into a list of lists like so `parse_dates=[['s1_startdate','s1_starttime'], ['s1_enddate', 's1_endtime']....]`

Comment: My advice is to create some dummy data which demonstrates the issue (without using your proprietary data).